# If a measure is an additive function exist also a subtractive map?

Tags: measure-theory, functions

> Technically, a measure is a function that assigns a non-negative real number or +∞ to (certain) subsets of a set X. It must further be countably additive

I try to find another definition

==> *a function that assigns a **negative** real number only or -∞ but not at same time a measure (not a function that assigns a non-negative real number or +∞)*

> an additive map, Z-linear map or additive function is a function that preserves the *addition* operation

I want an example of a function that preserves the substraction operation and an example of a function that assigns a negative real number only

Comment: By preserving addition, we mean that the measure of two *disjoint* sets is mapped to the sum of their measures. So, by "preserveing substraction", you mean that $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)$ whenever $B\subseteq A$?

Comment: Yes, exact: $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)$ in context of measures we talk about of σ-additivity or countable additivity. But I want to focus on 'negative' part but in my case is not a *measure* because *a function that assigns a* is limited to a negative real number only, never a a function that assigns a non-negative real number. So what function are we talking about?

Comment: At first note that the above relation has any sense only if both sets have finite measure. Also, you could search about "signed measures" - e.g here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure.

Comment: I am not convinced. In the signed measures one always refers to the measures, so first of all the concept of measurement is generalized and then the "negative part" of the measures is considered. But the sigma-additivity remains. I ask for something else, a function $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)$ which **is never** a measure and therefore I cannot even consider the generalization of the measures because a measure is a function that assigns a non-negative real number but in my situation I need a negative real number assignment as a preserving substraction

Comment: Do you restrict your function to take finite values?

Comment: Restrict to a negative real number only (in this case finite) or $-\infty$ but never a non-negative real number or +∞. Furthermore, it must never take $0$ values because for Peano axioms $0$ is a natural number. (because $0$ is the additive identity in arithmetic)